# Using React.js to display a different CTA button on the site's footer, depending on the page path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The footer must display a different CTA depending on if the user is on the Home page, or on the Product page. The product page is a single page that renders product information of the item selected on the home pages, and the way I have accomplished that is by using useParams(), and creating the a correlation between the page.id (comes from the data file ) and pageID.

I thought I could do the same thing for the footer, but I am getting an error claiming that everything is undefined, literally, everything.
This is my footer component. As you can see, I am importing the data for the footer from the data folder as "pageItems":

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import pageItems from '../../data/footerData';

function Footer() {
  const { pageID } = useParams();

  const individualPage = pageItems.find(page => page.id === pageID);

  return (
    <div className="footer-container">
      <p>{individualPage.copy}</p>

      <a href="https://www.lego.com/kids" target="_blank">
        <img src={individualPage.cta} alt="cta" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The data file (which is just a javascript file) is structured in the following way:

```
const footerData = [
  {
    id: '1',
    copy: 'You can find more fun at',
    cta: HomeCta,
    href: 'https://www.something.com',
  },
];
```

I am sure I could create the correlation between `<Route path="/:videoID">`  (which works), and the footer, but I can't seem to get it right.

Edit: This is how my routing page is set up at the moment:

```
    return (
        <Router>

            <Navbar />

            <Switch>
                <Route path="/:videoID">
                    <FeaturedVideo />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Home />
                </Route>
            </Switch>

            <Footer />

        </Router>
    );
}
```

Any help will really help. thank you so much in advance!

And as a side note, I am using the react version that uses react hooks

Comment: I would check to make sure that the `page.id` and `pageID` you're storing actually match each other because it looks like your `pageItems.find((page) => page.id === pageID)` is probably returning undefined everytime. I would also recommend adding a check of some kind to the place where you find the individual page by id so if it does end up being null your whole page doesn't crash.

Comment: @K-Log, Hi! Thanks for your comment. Yes, it does return undefined every time, and I don't know how to check or how to make them match each other any more than what the line ```page.id === pageID ``` does

Comment: I would start by adding a `console.log(pageID, pageItems)` before you return and checking that the pageItems array contains the correct items and that pageID is the correct value for the current page. You can checked the logged values by opening the inspector in your web browser and checking the console.

Comment: Do you use BrowseRouter, HashRouter? Or are you looking for a plain "javascript" solution, independent from React?

Comment: @Constantin Great question, I forgot to mention that I am using all of this: ```import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; ```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to keep `<Footer />` inside `<Router>`, but outside of the `<Switch>` and assign it as a component to a `<Route>` with as many `path` values as whereas you want it to display.

Here's a working version on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-newton-kliz1)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

const Footer = (props) => {
  let { videoID } = useParams();
  return <h3>Requested video ID: {videoID}</h3>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Router>
        <Link to="/2">VideoID2 </Link>
        <Link to="/3">VideoID3 </Link>
        <Link to="/4">VideoID4 </Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:videoID">
            <p>You are viewing</p>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/"></Route>
        </Switch>
        <Route exact path={["/", "/:videoID"]} component={Footer} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```